# Jslint use '||' operator instead of conditional operator

Tags: javascript, syntax, jslint

I have jslint complaining me to use `||` operator for below code,

```
query = ['browser' + (ieVersion ? ieVersion : 'UNKNOWN')]
```

I tried using `||` operator but that ends up in wrong result,

```
query = ['browser' + ieVersion || 'UNKNOWN'] 
// => ['browserundefined']
```

Comment: Sorry my bad, I did try with parentheses. Will update the question now

Comment: Um. But it works with parens, as in the answer you accepted.

Comment: Edit: I screwed. I actually din't use brackets. I will always worry about precedence from now on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) is wrong, try this:

```
query = ['browser' + (ieVersion || 'UNKNOWN')]
```

without extra parentheses `+` operator is stronger and JavaScript engine evaluates it as:

```
query = [('browser' + ieVersion) || 'UNKNOWN']
```

Notice that `'browser' + ieVersion` is never *falsy* so you'll never see `'UNKNOWN'`.

Answer (score 2):

brackets?

```
query = ['browser' + (ieVersion || 'UNKNOWN')]
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap the expression in parentheses:

```
query = ['browser' + (ieVersion || 'UNKNOWN')]
```